# Get data access from a website that is developed in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

I want to create a php app that will check ticket status from FIFA page that is created in angular js.

I tried to get data by using PHP, PHP curl Method, PHP file_get_content(), Jquery, and Javascript but all the time i got empty array.

hopefully there will some restrictions from angular js and server. link is given below please help me to check data from website.

https://tickets.fifa.com/Services/ADService.html?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about screen-scraping. Screen-scraping is a fragile solution because if they change the HTML for their page then your application will break.

That said, in your case the reason you got an empty array is because that site's webserver prevents screen-scraping. If you'd checked your php error log you would have seen a 403 forbidden error.

Simply put.. FIFA does not want their data to be stolen and used for purposes other than what they intended it for.